# the "enable"-member of my UIButton doesn't exist, why?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to make my button disabled why text editing is happening, so i use button.enabled = false, but this somehow doesn't work.
This is the bit that is causing me trouble.

```
@IBAction func saveButton(sender: UIButton) {
    <some code>
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    saveButton.enabled = false
}
```

and the error is "Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'enabled'"

I have tried with saveButton.userInteractionEnabled

So what is the problem

Comment: What does your declaration of `saveButton` look like?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `saveButton` is a function. That function takes a parameter of `UIButton`, but the function itself is not of type `UIButton`, it is of type `(UIButton) -> ()`.

`saveButton` needs to be a variable in order for your code to work. I'm assuming that `saveButton` is an `IBAction` that one of your buttons connect to. Find that button, create an `IBOutlet` for it, and use that button in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`.